# ubuntu 18.04 workspace to dock extension

Tags: 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

i am using ubuntu 18.04 when trying install extension workspace to dock it does install extension from http://extensions.gnome.org/ for shell version 3.26 (older in case of ubuntu 18.04 it is 3.28)and extension does not list shell version 3.28. Is there any other way to install it through zip file or something because

Comment: Have you actually tried installing it from http://extensions.gnome.org/? Many times an  extension which is not *officially* supported for newer GNOME shell version, installs and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try

```
apt install gnome-shell-extension-workspaces-to-dock
```

or install grom github

```
wget https://github.com/passingthru67/workspaces-to-dock/archive/master.zip -O /tmp/master.zip
unzip /tmp/master.zip -d /tmp/
#create extension folder if needed
mkdir '~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/'
mv '/tmp/workspaces-to-dock-master/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com' '~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com'
rm /tmp/master.zip
rm -rf /tmp/workspaces-to-dock-master/
```

then restart gnome-shell (Alt+F2, r, return)

Comment: thank @cmak.fr installed from github using your method of downloading and exterating to foledr extension